# How to resize stage in Adobe AIR to sit in Center when Full Screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe

I've looked all over the web to try and figure out how to resize an Adobe Air apps viewport rectangle. And I can't seem to figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is make a game with Adobe AIR so that when the "backspace" key is pressed (for testing right now) it enables the game to go into FULL_SCREEN.

The game currently launches in stage.displayState.NORMAL, and I'm going to implement an option in the future to enable FULL_SCREEN.

However, the problem that I can't seem to figure out is how to get my stage to align in the center of the screen when FULL_SCREEN is active with Adobe AIR.

What I want is that when you go into FullScreen the stage is in the center like the first image posted.

[image: http://cl.ly/image/190t3u3U1C3e] 
<- This is the game when the adl launches with everything being centered.

[image] 
<- And when the app goes into FULL_SCREEN, the stage aligns to the TOP_LEFT.

This is my Main.AS that handles the Stage Setup. How can I align the stage to be set in the middle when it goes into FullScreen. Like Binding of Issac?

```
[SWF(frameRate="60", width="1920", height="1080", backgroundColor="#000000")]
public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var _starling:Starling;
    public static var screenWidth:Number = 0.0;
    public static var screenHeight:Number = 0.0;

    public function Main() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageSetup); 
    }

    private function stageSetup(e:Event):void  {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageSetup);

        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;

        var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        screenWidth = stage.fullScreenWidth  > 1920 ? 1920 : stage.fullScreenWidth;
        screenHeight = stage.fullScreenHeight > 1080 ? 1080  : stage.fullScreenHeight;

        Starling.handleLostContext = false;
        _starling = new Starling( GameEngine, stage);
        _starling.antiAliasing = 1;
        _starling.start();

        _starling.showStats = true; 
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, escKeyOverride); 
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enableFullScreen);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize);   
    }
    private function enableFullScreen(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
           stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
           stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        } 
        else {
            //build in button listener for settings to resize back to normal
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        }
    }
    private function escKeyOverride(e:KeyboardEvent):void  {
         if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    private function resize(e:Event):void {
        var viewPortRectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        viewPortRectangle.width     = stage.stageWidth;
        viewPortRectangle.height    = stage.stageHeight;
        Starling.current.viewPort   = viewPortRectangle;
        _starling.stage.stageWidth  = stage.stageWidth;
        _starling.stage.stageHeight = stage.stageHeight;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the fullscreen, you must set the `stage.scaleMode` to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`, and set the `stage.align` to `""`
In code:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
stage.align = ""
```

Comment: Awesome! This seemed to do the trick! Thanks a bunch. One question. Would you happen to know why when Escape is pressed it aligns the stage to the top_left in Full screen?

Comment: Set the align whenever you go in fullscreen mode, when you press Escape, AIR sets the `stage.displayMode` to `StadeDisplayState.NORMAL`, and probably does something with the align, not sure. Set the `stage.align` to `""` in your `escKeyOverride` function, that should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I was putting in stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
stage.align = "", in the ESC function and it wasn't working. So I just put in set-align''. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: In my case it's worked with "stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;"